# ruby gem, Rails.root is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am building a simple gem. I want to load a file 'config/simple.yml'. In lib/simple.rb I have:

```
class Simple
  def self.init
    puts Rails.root
  end
end
```

After bundle main_app, I run "rails c", then I call Simple.init, it prints `nil`.

Comment: In main_app/config/application.rb. I add require 'simple' to load it

Answer (score 1):

Yeap. in file config/application.rb place "require 'simple'" to bottom of file will fix it :D